# message:(#200) App does not have permission to make this call in ios application using facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7

I want to like and comment in my iOS application.But the problem is whenever I call my API the response comes in the form of this `error:message:(#200)'. App does not have permission to make this call and sometimes it will give input parameter is required.The permissions i give are 'basic_info','email','user_likes' and 'read_stream'. I am passing object id and access token in my like and comment API.

Like API code:

```
NSString *theWholeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/likes?access_token=%@",self.friendId,[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken];

NSLog(@"Value of theWholeUrl%@",theWholeUrl);
NSURL *facebookUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:theWholeUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:facebookUrl];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the publish_actions permission to be able to like and comment on content programmatically via the API.

Comment: After giving publish_actions permissions,again it is giving the same error.The problem is it will never ask for publish action permissions whenever i am trying to log in.

Comment: This is my code to give permissions:                                                        NSArray *readPermissions = [[NSArray alloc]         initWithObjects:@"basic_info",@"email",@"user_birthday",@"read_stream",@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:readPermissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
 }]